Why is my Javafx code refusing to run after a GitHub merge?
I have a very simple menu program I have made in JavaFX on Visual Studio Code, the code works fine on its own, but after merging with a larger project, the code refuses to work. Giving me a "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" error.
I've tried updating the launch.json, moving the Javafx files into a subfolder, and moving the javafx files into a seperate folder to test them, all of which didn't work.
Here's the Menu file
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Menu extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fullscrn.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

and the Launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Menu",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "Menu",
            "projectName": "Menutst_8fc80d72"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Main",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/lukas/OneDrive/Desktop/javafx-sdk-22.0.1\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "Main",
            "projectName": "Menutst_8fc80d72",
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "App",
            "args": ""
        }
    ]
}

C:/users... is where my main install of the Javafx libs is kept. I also tried using the project lib folder of JavaFX (the one that is kept with the other code files) and that changed nothing as well.

Eventually, Java applications are run by executing a java command, whether is that from a command line or by an IDE.  What is the complete java command used to run your application?  You can edit the question to add this missing piece of information.

The launch configurations without a module path are not correctly configured to run a JavaFX application.  I recommend deleting them.

Your --module-path is wrong.  For the JavaFX Windows SDK, the modules are in the lib directory under the SDK installation.1
Change:
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/lukas/OneDrive/Desktop/javafx-sdk-22.0.1\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

To:
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/lukas/OneDrive/Desktop/javafx-sdk-22.0.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

This is documented in the openjfx getting started instructions for JavaFX in Visual Studio Code, section "Non-modular from the IDE" part 4 "Create and update launch configurations".
I do recommend using a build tool (Maven or Gradle) rather than manually configuring the IDE like this.  The getting started documentation I linked tells you how to integrate a build tool with your IDE.  Alternatively, you can use a Java distribution that includes JavaFX (e.g. Bellsoft Liberica "Full JDK" or Azul Zulu "JDK FX"), then you don't need to worry about setting module paths.


I have only a x64 Mac available, so I can't validate that this works on Windows (nor do I use Visual Studio Code).  It should work according to the documentation.  However, the Mac JavaFX SDK and Windows JavaFX SDK have different layouts.  The Windows SDK has a bin directory where native components (.dll) are placed, but the Mac SDK places native components (.dylib) in the lib directory where the jars are.  So there could be some differences in the setup requirements for these two distributions.


Unfortunately, that dies not seem to be the issue. The same error remains after adding the 'lib' path into the launch.Json.

As requested in my earlier comment: “ What is the complete java command used to run your application? You can edit the question to add this missing piece of information. ”.

Also: “ I do recommend using a build tool (Maven or Gradle) rather than manually configuring the IDE like this. “

These two pieces of code in the Launch.Json were messing with the JavaFX stuff. Deleting them had no adverse effect on the rest of the code and everything is running smoothly now. I also forgot to add /lib into the filename.
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Menu",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "Menu",
        "projectName": "Menutst_8fc80d72"
    },
 {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Current File",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "App",
        "args": ""
    }

So that was the problem! Thanks to everyone who helped me out.
